# Datetime order problem in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have a column of a datagridview which contains dates. The range in this case is from January 1st to February 25th. When I click the column to select an ascending or descending order, the values are sorted by day and not by month. I can't understand why

[DataGridView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AByXz.png)

My code:

```
column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.Name = "DATAV";
column.HeaderText = "Data arrotondata";
column.DataPropertyName = "DATAV";
column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
dgvStampingViewer.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: it is misbehaving because the datatype of your column is `string` and not `DateTime`. Which is why it is sorting in alphabetical order. if you are using a DataReader to load data in DataGridView, check the datatype

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the column is read as string, and order by first letters, you need to change the properties like datatime
add this

```
column.Format= "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: I tried `column.DefaultCellStyle.Format= "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";` but it doesn't works

Comment: i dont know from where you take your column value but put this Convert.ToDateTime(ColumnReference) and it should work